# Visualizer: An unhandled exception of type 'System.CannotUnloadAppDomainException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I am attempting to write a Visual Studio Visualizer for Visual Studio 2015 following this guide:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164759.aspx

However I want to use WPF instead of WinForms.

For the visualizer I have this code:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers;
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(Visualizer.DebuggerSide), typeof(VisualizerObjectSource),
    Target = typeof(string), Description = "Visualizer")]
namespace Visualizer
{
    public class DebuggerSide : DialogDebuggerVisualizer
    {
        protected override void Show(IDialogVisualizerService windowService, IVisualizerObjectProvider objectProvider)
        {
            var window = new MainWindow();
            window.ShowDialog();
        }

        public static void TestShowVisualizer(object thingToVisualize)
        {
            var visualizerHost = new VisualizerDevelopmentHost(thingToVisualize, typeof(DebuggerSide));
            visualizerHost.ShowVisualizer();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I call it from a console application to test as follows:

```
namespace Visualizer.Debug
{
    using System;
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = "test";
            DebuggerSide.TestShowVisualizer(data);
        }
    }
}
```

The code runs well and the window is launched at the point of `window.ShowDialog`. Once I close the window the code returns from `Show` and throws an exception at `visualizerHost.ShowVisualizer();`.

The exception is:

> System.CannotUnloadAppDomainException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2146234347   Message=Error while unloading appdomain.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131015)   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
>          at System.AppDomain.Unload(AppDomain domain)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.DebugViewerShim.ManagedShim.Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.DebugViewerShim.IManagedViewerHost.CreateViewer(IntPtr
>   hwnd, Object hostServicesParam, IPropertyProxyEESide proxy)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.VisualizerDevelopmentHost.EEProxyImpl.ShowVisualizer(IntPtr
>   parentWindow)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.VisualizerDevelopmentHost.ShowVisualizer()
>          at Visualizer.DebuggerSide.TestShowVisualizer(Object thingToVisualize) in C:\git\Visualizer\Visualizer\Class1.cs:line 20
>          at Visualizer.Debug.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\git\Visualizer\Visualizer.Debug\Program.cs:line 10
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

Thinking the error might be due to the WPF code trying to return to the Visual Studio code I tried launching the WPF window in a completely separate AppDomain but when I then tried to unload that AppDomain I got the same error.

Code for MainWindow:

```
namespace Visualizer
{
    using System.Windows;
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, that was incredibly annoying!

I am on a Touchscreen Enabled computer and therefore WPF registers for Stylus Input. When the WPF window unloads itself and the `AppDomain` attempts to unload, the Stylus Input thread will keep running and block the AppDomain from unloading. (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/798279/stylus-input-thread-prevents-appdomain-from-unloading )

I initially tried to fix this using a separate AppDomain and ensuring I called `Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown()` when closing the Main Window as suggested in the linked article. In my visualizer the `Show` method became:

```
protected override void Show(IDialogVisualizerService windowService, IVisualizerObjectProvider objectProvider)
{
    var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("My Friendly Domain");

    CrossAppDomainDelegate action = () =>
    {
        var window = new MainWindow();

        window.ShowDialog();
    };

    domain.DoCallBack(action);

    AppDomain.Unload(domain);
}
```

And the MainWindow had the following code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // Without this AppDomain unloading will fail and hate you forever...
    Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();

    base.OnClosing(e);
}
```

This works for debugging from a console application however it seems Visual Studio does not allow you to invoke `CrossAppDomainDelegates` in Visualizers and I got some form of Serialization exception.

### Answer

The obvious next step, since I don't give a damn about Stylus support is to remove it completely. The code for this is given here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901337(v=vs.90).aspx

This makes the code in `Visualizer`:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers;

[assembly: System.Diagnostics.DebuggerVisualizer(
    typeof(Visualizer.DebuggerSide),
    typeof(VisualizerObjectSource),
    Target = typeof(string),
    Description = "Visualizer")]
namespace Visualizer
{
    public class DebuggerSide : DialogDebuggerVisualizer
    {
        protected override void Show(IDialogVisualizerService windowService, IVisualizerObjectProvider objectProvider)
        {
            var window = new MainWindow();

            window.ShowDialog();
        }

        public static void TestShowVisualizer(object thingToVisualize)
        {
            var visualizerHost = new VisualizerDevelopmentHost(thingToVisualize, typeof(DebuggerSide));
            visualizerHost.ShowVisualizer();
        }
    }
}
```

And `MainWindow`:

```
namespace Visualizer
{
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Input;

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            DisableWPFTabletSupport();

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static void DisableWPFTabletSupport()
        {
            // Get a collection of the tablet devices for this window.  
            var devices = Tablet.TabletDevices;

            if (devices.Count == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            var inputManagerType = typeof(InputManager);

            var stylusLogic = inputManagerType.InvokeMember("StylusLogic",
                        BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                        null, InputManager.Current, null);

            if (stylusLogic == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var stylusLogicType = stylusLogic.GetType();

            while (devices.Count > 0)
            {
                // Remove the first tablet device in the devices collection.
                stylusLogicType.InvokeMember("OnTabletRemoved",
                        BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                        null, stylusLogic, new object[] { (uint)0 });
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

### Simpler Answer

It turns out both steps were overkill, really I just needed to keep the call to `Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown()` in the `OnClosing` event handler and call the main window normally:

```
protected override void Show(IDialogVisualizerService windowService, IVisualizerObjectProvider objectProvider)
{
    var window = new MainWindow();

    window.ShowDialog();
}
```

And main window:

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();

    base.OnClosing(e);
}
```